# Javascript Toggle closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with a jQuery script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#expand").hide();
$(".expander").show();

$('.expander').click(function () {
    $("#expand").toggle("slide");
    $(".main-menu").css("display", "none");
});
```

});

Here is the HTML code for that, I need to modify the structure?!

```
            <a type="button"href="search.html" class="btn btn-default main-menu"">
                <img src="nav01.png" class="center-block" alt="Navigation Icon 01" />
                <label class="text-center">Rechercher</label>
            </a>
            <a type="button" href="legratuit://#!section=18945605" class="btn btn-default main-menu">
                <img src="nav02.png" class="center-block" alt="Navigation Icon 01" />
                <label class="text-center">Publier</label>
            </a>
            <a type="button" href="legratuit://#!section=18945993" class="btn btn-default">
                <img src="nav03.png" class="center-block" alt="Navigation Icon 02" />
                <label class="text-center">Alertes</label>
            </a>
            <a type="button" href="legratuit://#!section=18724784" class="btn btn-default">
                <img src="nav04.png" class="center-block" alt="Navigation Icon 03" />
                <label class="text-center">Favoris</label>
            </a>

            <a type="button" href="legratuit://#!section=18145899" class="btn btn-default expander">
                <img src="dot.png" class="center-block" alt="Navigation Icon 04" />
                <label class="text-center">Autres</label>
            </a>
            <span id="expand" style="display: none;">
                <a type="button" href="legratuit://#!section=18145899" class="btn btn-default">
                    <img src="nav05.png" class="center-block" alt="Navigation Icon 04" />
                    <label class="text-center">Compte</label>
                </a>
                <a type="button" href="legratuit://#!section=18145899" class="btn btn-default">
                    <img src="contact.png" class="center-block" alt="Navigation Icon 04" />
                    <label class="text-center">Contact</label>
                </a>
            </span>
```

The problem is when I close the toggle how can I display : inline-block the .main-menu?

Comment: use ``if`` to check ``$("#expand")`` is close then change ``$(".main-menu").css("display", "inline-block");``

Comment: So how can I verify if that #expand is closed?

Comment: add your html too

Comment: what is the html tag?

Comment: I uploaded the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *.toggle* twice:

```
$('.expander').click(function () {
    $("#expand").toggle("slide");
    $(".main-menu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: That was so easy! Thank you!